# Excel VBA - Autofill only works during debug

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I am trying to copy cells from a sheet in a table on another sheet, and trying to autofill the formulas contained in the table to the newly created rows.

My macro basically takes all visible cells from a sorted table in sheet "Demands" and copies their value directly under the table in the sheet "ITA & IO-EOTP". The table automatically expands, but not all formulas are applied to the new row (some are, though). I then call an AutoFill from the row above to the new row. When all new IDs are copied over, I sort everything.

The thing is: while the AutoFill works when I'm debugging line by line, it is simply skipped when I launch the macro without breakpoints... I don't know what is the cause of this ! I've already spent the whole day trying to figure it out, and it's driving me nuts !!

Here is the whole macro:

```
Public Sub InsertIntoITA()
Dim y, availPos, startPos As Long
Dim currCell, currSel As Range

'make it fast, plz
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("Demands").Select

demandsImported = True

'check if demands were imported first
If demandsImported Then

    'select all new demands
    y = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Set currSel = Range("A2:A" & y).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    'get first position after the table in ITA sheet
    availPos = Sheets("ITA & IO-EOTP").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    startPos = availPos - 1

    'check if there are demands at all
    If Not currSel.Count = 0 Then
        For Each currCell In currSel

            'if cell contains #N/A (not what we want) it means the user hasn't attributed a new ID to the demand yet
            'if it doesn't, proceed to copy the ID at the end of the table in ITA sheet
            If Not IsError(currCell) Then
                Sheets("ITA & IO-EOTP").Range("A" & availPos).Value = currCell.Value

                'then autofill from the line above, to ensure formulas are applied
                Range("B" & availPos - 1 & ":P" & availPos - 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & availPos - 1 & ":P" & availPos)

                'allow the table to automatically expand to include the new ID then
                'increment available position
                availPos = availPos + 1
            End If
        Next currCell

        'Then order them
        Sheets("ITA & IO-EOTP").ListObjects("ITATable").Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
        Sheets("ITA & IO-EOTP").ListObjects("ITATable").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("ITATable[[#All],[ONE-IT ID]]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With Sheets("ITA & IO-EOTP").ListObjects("ITATable").Sort
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End If
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

I hope you'll be able to see where the problem is...

(Also quick note: the ITA Sheet has a macro that sets .EnableCalculation to False whenever it is activated, don't know if it matters/helps)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Sheets("ITA & IO-EOTP").EnableCalculation = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Is your code running on the same sheet in both cases? I see a generic statement of: `ThisWorkbook.Activate` and `Sheets("Demands").Select`, so maybe it is taking a range from a different place than you intended?

Comment: @Roberto The code can be called from a macro button added in the ribbon in any sheet, as long as it is in the correct workbook (the one that contains the code, which also contains the sheets). The statements are there to ensure this. But really, the focus of the question here is why does it work during debug, and not when the macro runs free ? :/

Comment: I would suggest you to use `copy / pastespecial xlpasteformulas`. I tried few times to deal with autofill and most of the time it ended up with nothing. `Copy / pastespecial xlpasteformulas` will do excacly the same as autofill.

Comment: @Skwiggl - does any error message get generated if you remove `On Error Resume Next`? Do you have that in place for any particular reason?

Comment: @Roberto - I removed the `On Error Resume Next`, but to no avail (and no errors pop up)

Comment: @lowak - Isn't that a lot slower than the Autofill ? I might end up doing that, but if there's a faster alternative, I'd prefer it :)

Comment: Are any of your variables being populated from calculated cells in your worksheet? You have turned screenupdating and calculation off which means any calculated cell will not have a value in it until it is switched back on. This may be why it works when stepping through the code as the screen updates in debug mode.

Comment: @Dave - when you speak about variables, what exactly do you mean ? Other than that, most of the columns in the table on ITA sheet have formulas that check the ID. The remaining columns that don't have formulas are filled in with another macro (which works, was implemented before I arrived here). Thing is for example: Columns B to E contain formulas, but only the one in col E is ported over to the new lines, B,C & D stay blank and empty...

Comment: @Dave - I have tried and reapplied calculations (both Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic AND Sheets("ITA & IO-EOTP").EnableCalculation = True) but apart taking ages to complete, autofill still doesn't work...

Comment: @Skwiggl I don't think it will take much more time then autofill. All you need to do is copy the range and then paste in the range. It does not need to be a loop for thousands of cells.

Comment: What I was referring to is if either the value you want to copy or the value you are using to determine the size of the range to fill have not been calculated, the autofill would not work. If your code populates a cell, then refers to it later it the value may not have been written to that cell yet if screenupdating is off therefore the value would be 0.

Comment: @Dave - Oh right I understand what you mean :) But you can see that my code here doesn't do this kind of things (I suppose you can ?) Anyway I found the answer so it's not relevant anymore :p thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found the culprit... I just needed to activate the ITA sheet before the compiler enters the For block...

```
        Sheets("ITA & IO-EOTP").Activate
        For Each currCell In currSel

            'if cell contains #N/A (not what we want) it means the user hasn't attributed a new ID to the demand yet
            'if it doesn't, proceed to copy the ID at the end of the table in ITA sheet
            If Not IsError(currCell) Then
                Sheets("ITA & IO-EOTP").Range("A" & availPos).Value = currCell.Value

                'then autofill from the line above, to ensure formulas are applied
                Range("B" & availPos - 1 & ":P" & availPos - 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & availPos - 1 & ":P" & availPos)

                'increment available position
                availPos = availPos + 1
            End If
        Next currCell
```

... Now it works with both autofill or copy/paste

Comment: Just out of curiosity. If you would add `Sheets("ITA & IO-EOTP").` to your autofill, it may work even without activating this sheet.

Comment: @lowak - Thanks for the +1 :) unfortunately, adding `Sheets("ITA & IO-EOTP").` before autofill and removing `Sheets("ITA & IO-EOTP").Activate` throws a 1004, dunno why :/ I'll stick with `Sheets("ITA & IO-EOTP").Activate` :P

Comment: Yes, of course. Try this: `Sheets("ITA & IO-EOTP").Range("B" & availPos - 1 & ":P" & availPos - 1).AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("ITA & IO-EOTP").Range("B" & availPos - 1 & ":P" & availPos)`